# How to recognize a proper sub game

Tags: game-theory

[image]

The extensive form game in both diagrams appears the same, why the difference in the number of subgames?

Answer (score 3):

Subgames have to start at a trivial information set, that is, a node where the player is sure he is at that node. In the right diagram in your question, the two nodes are connected, so player $1$ is not informed of the action made by player $2$, and thus, the information set is non-trivial. Therefore, in the left diagram the number of subgames is $3$, while in the right diagram it is $1$.